# getting certain component of all elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have stored some elements of a struct, let's call it `myStruct`, in a vector.
Now I want to get a **certain component** of this struct **of all** the **elements** in my **vector**.

Is there a possibility to do this *fast*, without using a for-loop? Is there an equivalent solution for `deque`?

```
struct myStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
};

vector<myStruct> vec;

//creating some data and push back to vector
myStruct ms0,ms1;
ms0.a = 5;
ms1.a = 10;             
vec.push_back(ms0);
vec.push_back(ms1);

//now I want to get the component a of ms0 and ms1
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a `for` loop?

Comment: What do you want to do with the subset of components?  And, what is your reason for wanting to avoid a loop?

Comment: Use std::transform with the appropriate functor to pick out your element.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I have much data stored, so that I'm searching for a fast way as `for` loops

Comment: @AnonMail Which binary operation can by used in `transform`?

Comment: What are you doing to the members afterwards?

Comment: Whichever solution you find, it requires looping the vector which is `O(n)` in the length `n` of the vector. Since element access is `O(1)`, a `for` loop is about as efficient as it gets. If the resulting cache misses are really a bottleneck, consider storing the data differently so that all the values of `a` are adjacent in memory. If readability matters and you want your code to convey your intention clearly, consider using a `for` loop.

Comment: @black you can use everything you can imagine, which operates on vector elements in `std::transform`. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two vectors, one storing component `a`, one storing component `b`, instead of one vector storing pairs (`a`, `b`).

If this doesn't work for you, you can do something like (this is C++11 or higher):

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
[] (myStruct &v) {std::cout << v.a << '\n';} );
```

But this is not (in terms of complexity) better than a `for` loop.

Comment: how would storing components in two separate vectors help?

Comment: Well then `a`s and `b`s would be contiguous in memory, so you would cut by half your cache misses if all your operations are on one field of this structure, which is not negligible for a big quantity of data as the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are sequence containers, more specifically arrays that can change their size dynamically, thus to access all of their elements it will take time proportional to their size, `n`. Thus the answer to your first question:

> Is there a possibility to do this fast, without using a for-loop?

is: No

As for the second question:

> Is there an equivalent solution for `deque`?

Yes, there is and it will look the same as the one posted, with the small difference in the container which instead of `vector<myStruct> vec;` will be `std::deque<int> mydeque;`

Answer (score -1):

Internally `vector` uses arrays so you can directly access its elements using `[]` operator,

eg:

```
cout<< vec[0].a << vec[1].a;
```